# UIImagePickerController slow to stop recording and dismiss

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using UIImagePicker to record video in my app. I recently implemented a slide view controller, and I've noticed that the UIImagePicker interface is slower. Its not too bad on loading and starting video recording, but really slow when stopping video and dismissing the view controller. Stopping video infact keeps recording for 5-6 seconds. Pressing the 'Use' button after it has stopped recording also takes a similar time.

I've tried it when not plugged in, and its better but still quite slow.

- Firstly, how would I go about analysing speed here?
- Does anybody have any ideas as to why including a reveal controller would slow things down?

Thanks,
Mike